# Swift: Casting collections, and creating custom convertible protocols

Tags: swift

Consider this `Person` class, which simply implements `StringLiteralConvertible` and assigns the string literal to `name`:

```
class Person : StringLiteralConvertible {
    var name : String?

    typealias StringLiteralType = String

    required init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        println("stringLiteral \(value)")
        name = value
    }

    typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String

    required init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
        println("extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral \(value)")
        name = value
    }

    typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = Character

    required init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
        println("unicodeScalarLiteral \(value)")
        name = "\(value)"
    }
}
```

This allows me to create a `Person` instance using a string:

```
let aaron : Person = "Aaron"
```

I can even cast an array of `Person`s from an array of strings:

```
let names = ["John", "Jane"] as [Person]
```

However this only works with string *literals*. If I use a string variable, it fails:

```
let aaronString = "Aaron"
let aaron : Person = aaronString
// Error: 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'Person'
```

Similarly, trying to cast an array of non-literal strings fails:

```
let nameStrings = ["John", "Jane"]
let people : [Person] = nameStrings
// Error: 'String' is not identical to 'Person'
```

I have three questions:

1. Is there another protocol I can implement to cast a *non-literal* string to a `Person`? I'd like to do this so I can cast entire collections to convert the objects.
2. If no to #1, is map + an initializer the best way to perform the conversion myself?

   ```
   let nameStrings = ["John", "Jane"]
   let people = nameStrings.map{Person(name: $0)}
   ```
3. If yes to #1, is there a similar approach I can use to specify an approach to convert two objects which are unrelated in hierarchy? That is, can I work around this error without an initializer?

   ```
   let rikerPerson : Person = "Riker"
   let rikerEmployee = rikerPerson as Employee
   // Error: 'Person' is not convertible to 'Employee'
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What you are describing as “casting” isn’t really casting (in the way that, say, `s = “fred”; ns = s as NSString` is, or that casts in C++ are).

   ```
   let names = ["John", "Jane"] as [Person]
   ```

   is just another a way of writing:

   ```
   let names: [Person] = ["John", "Jane"]
   ```

   that is, a way of telling Swift which of the many possible versions of `StringLiteralConvertible` to use (and not the one for `String`, which is the default).

   Put it another way – your `as` is fulfilling a similar function to the `as` in this snippet that disambiguates two overloaded functions that differ only by return type:

   ```
   func f() -> String { return "foo" }
   func f() -> Int { return 42 }

   let i = f() as Int    // i will be 42
   let s = f() as String // s will be “foo"
   ```

   No “conversion” is going on here – the `as` is just being used to disambiguate which `f` Swift calls.  It’s the same with which `init(stringLiteral:)` is chosen.
2. Definitely (but only if you put a space between `map` and the `{ }` ;-).

   If you’re concerned about the waste of converting it all to an array just to do some other thing with it, check out `lazy(a).map`
3. Nope.  In the betas, there used to be a `__conversion() -> T` method you could implement to do “casts” like this on your own classes – or more importantly, allowed you to pass your `Person` class into a function that took an `Employee` argument and have it be converted implicitly.  But that got disappeared.  Generally that kind of implicit conversion is antithetical to Swift’s style, except in rare cases (Obj-C and C interop, and implicit wrapping in optionals, being the main ones).  You have to write an `init` for `Employee` that takes a `Person` (or some class or protocol that `Person` conforms to), and then call it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough clarification in #1 and suggestions in #2. I'll submit a radar requesting the reintroduction of `__conversion()`.